# Не могу собрать драйвер QMYSQL.

Tags: qt

Все делал по инструкции https://wiki.belykh.me/wiki/index.php/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_MySQL_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_Qt
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такая ошибка. Всем за ранее,спасибо

Comment: А сама библиотека для работы с mysql у вас установлена? Пути к ней прописаны?

Comment: Да, переустанавливал несколько раз. Пути прописал,  как в инструкции. Скачивал уже готовые драйвера, тоже не работает. При подключении к бд в Qt, тоже ошибки undefined  reference to